# Proving each conditional statement is a tautology

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm having trouble trying to show that each of the conditional statement below is a tautology without using a truth table. I'm assuming you would have to use logical equivalence to figure this out. I know that a tautology is when the truth value of the conditional statements are all true. Can someone help me solve this? Please show me step by step how I would solve this with an explanation so that I can better understand this.

$1.$ $[\neg p \land (p \lor q)] \to q$
$2.$ $[(p \to q) \land (q \to r)] \to (p \to r)$
$3.$ $[p \land (p \to q)] \to q$

Comment: If you don't want to use truth tables, then what _do_ you want to use? Informal reasoning? Hilbert-style proofs? Natural deduction? Algebraic rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

My first time posting an answer, pardon my formatting.

1. [¬p∧(p∨q)]→q[¬p∧(p∨q)]→q
2. [(p→q)∧(q→r)]→(p→r)[(p→q)∧(q→r)]→(p→r)
3. [p∧(p→q)]→q

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Rif to :

- Kenneth Rosen, [Discrete mathematics and its applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=55GaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35) (7th ed), page 35 :

**Exercise 10** asked you to show that the above formulae are *tautologies* using truth tables.

Then :

> **Exercise 12** : Show that each conditional statement in **Exercise 10** is a tautology without using truth tables.

We have to use the *logical equivalences* listed in page 27 and the method described in **Example 8** [page 30], i.e. we have to transform the formula through logical equivalences until we get $T$ (*true*).

Thus, for :

> 1. $[¬p∧(p∨q)]→q$

first of all, we have to remove the *conditional* using *Material implication* [see **Table 7**, page 28] :

> $\lnot [\lnot p \land (p \lor q)] \lor q$

and then use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to "move" inside the *negation* :

> $[p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)] \lor q$.

Then we apply [Distributive laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) :

> $([(p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor \lnot q)] \lor q) \equiv ([T \land (p \lor \lnot q)] \lor q)$

followed by *Identity laws* : $T \land a \equiv a$ :

> $((p \lor \lnot q) \lor q) \equiv (p \lor (q \lor \lnot q))$

by [Associative laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property).

Finally, we apply *Domination laws* : $a \lor T \equiv T$ :

> $p \lor T \equiv T$

and we can conclude that formula 1. is a *tautology*.

---

The same proof can be easily modified in order to solve also 3.

Answer (score 0):

Show that each of these conditional statements is a tautology by using truth tables. (And then without using the truth    tables.)
a) (p ∧ q) → p         b) p → (p ∨ q)         c) ￢p → (p → q)